# EFA on inherently skewed questionnaire data

Tags: categorical-data, factor-analysis, assumptions, normality-assumption, skewness

I have a very large dataset in which participants were presented with short vignettes that contain fear-eliciting scenarios. Participants rated how *fearful* they found found these vignettes on a Likert scale from 1-7. The aim of this data was to run an EFA to examine what latent variables drive responding to these vignettes.

I have valid responses from N = 467 participants on 142 of these vignettes, and a dozen neutral vignettes that were thrown in just to make sure that people respond sensibly. When I shove the data through a factor analysis with oblique rotation, I get interpretable factors (i.e., they mesh with some theoretical predictions).

My concern, however, is that the data is inherently very much positively skewed. The reason for this is that the individual vignettes are constructed to be fear-eliciting. This means that there are going to be a lot more responses above the median of the scale than below it. (The control vignettes are basically the reflection of fear ones, which is what you'd assume, and they come out as a very distinct factor). The big picture idea is that responding will differ from vignette to vignette as a function of the fear elicitors within the different vignettes.

It has been a long time since I have done factor analysis, but my understanding is that it is an extension of correlation/regression and therefore normality is a key assumption. Formal tests of univariate normality come out as one would expect with each vignette being very reasonably skewed, and the [MVN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MVN/index.html) package for R states that the data fail multivariate normality tests.

I tried to take the [Tabachnick and Fidell](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Tabachnick-Using-Multivariate-Statistics-6th-Edition/PGM332849.html) recommended approach of transforming the data, but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Any other approaches to cleaning up the data that are worth trying? Am I better off looking to something other than factor analysis?

Comment: Can you share some of your descriptive normality-related statistics for your items, so that we can better gauge the severity of your situation? Also, in the event that you need to do *something*, your options will be somewhat dictated by which software packages you have access to, so it might helpful to have some context for the environment(s) you plan to analyze your data in.

Comment: @jsakaluk, sure, is there something specific that you're after? To give you an idea of what the data look like, I quickly pulled out the [histograms](http://imgur.com/a4fVmJP) and [Q-Q plots](http://imgur.com/IXufQoJ) for the first 12 variables. I also have a [multivariate Q-Q plot](http://imgur.com/GPP7zTC) generated by MVN. Is there anything more specific that'd be informative? Would kurtosis values be helpful?

Comment: @jsakaluk, to get at your second point, I have access to SPSS and R. I have a lot of experience using SPSS, and am (very slowly) trying to learn R.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is that the variables aren't even continuous: They are ordinal.  A lot of people would do factor analysis on the raw data anyway, but there has been some research on better approaches.

One good paper is [Joreskog and Moustaki (2006)](http://www.ssicentral.com/lisrel/techdocs/orfiml.pdf) and papers cited therein.